# Get price with web-scraping PHP

Tags: php, web-scraping

I am new to scraping and I am using the php library "PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser" to get the price and date of the product on this website: http://www.mercadopublico.cl/TiendaFicha/Ficha?idProducto=1557392

[This image shows the values that I want to obtain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYRZw.jpg)

[This information delivers the inspect elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgTuI.jpg)

I have the following code:

```php
<?php

include('simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php');

// get DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.mercadopublico.cl/TiendaFicha/Ficha?idProducto=1557392');

// find all span tags with id=spPrecio
foreach($html->find('span#spPrecio') as $e)
    echo $e->outertext . '<br>';
?>
```

But I can't get what I need, I only get data such as the title h3. I have tried many solutions and nothing has worked for me, please I need your help.

Thank you.

Comment: Check the HTML source code (not the DOM inspector view) of the page you are trying to read this value from … notice something?

Comment: You might want to use this selector: `#spPrecio > font > font`

Comment: @04FS I checked the html source and it doesn't show the price, what could be the problem?

Comment: It is apparently not part of the initial HTML code of the page delivered by the server, but gets inserted into the document later via JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inspecting network flow in browsers developer tool one can see that HTML is partially loaded (the one you get with `file_get_html`) and after that is modified by JavaScript via XHR request. 
Your price is loaded via this link:

```
http://www.mercadopublico.cl/TiendaFicha/Ficha/ObtenerPrecioMenor?idProducto=1557392&idConvenioMarco=5800221&_=1574869395485
```

Where parameters are:

```
idProducto=1557392
idConvenioMarco=5800221
_=1574869395485
```

idProducto - is in your provided link.

IdConvenionMarco is found somewhere in DOM you downloaded:

`<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field IdConvenioMarco must be a number." data-val-required="The IdConvenioMarco field is required." id="hdnIdConvenioMarco" name="ProductosConvenio.IdConvenioMarco" type="hidden" value="5800221" />`

And the last one _ is UNIX timestamp in milliseconds.
Having those 3 parameters can provide you any product price. Response is in JSON:

```
{"Precio":"$ 2.178","Estado":true}
```